# How to mock Spring HandlerInterceptorAdapter in an integration test?

Tags: java, spring, mocking, integration-testing, interceptor

Say I have some `FooInterceptor`:

```
public class FooInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
   // ...
}
```

Which is configured in the context:

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
     <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="my.package.FooInterceptor"/>
     </mvc:interceptor>
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

I am creating an integration test for some controller:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = "/context.xml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    ...
}
```

I have tried to mock it via creating a custom configuration:

```
@Configuration
static class Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FooInterceptor getFooInterceptor() {
        return mock(FooInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to me to be working. The actual `FooInterceptor` is still produced and involved into the test.

How to properly mock it?

Answer (score 3):

You can go with the following as suggested by Luana FM in the previous answer. Also you'll need one line of mock code to return the response of interceptor as **true** in `@BeforeEach` block.

```java
        @BeforeEach
        public void before() {
          MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
          mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
              .standaloneSetup(controller)
              .addInterceptors(interceptor)
              .build();
        when(interceptor.preHandle(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I went ahead and wrote some code to solve the same question I had. Within our test case project, We can mock the interceptor by explicitly defining our own interceptor that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter which will have mock logic mimicking our original interceptor

```
public class MockTenantInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
```

We can initialize the mock interceptor class without autowiring and proceed to register it within TestConfiguration class. Do make sure since we will have 2 configuration classes one for WebConfig and TestConfig to add the spring profile annotation that prevents your production interceptor from been invoked.

```
@Profile("test")
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class TestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        MockTenantInterceptor mockTenantInterceptor = new MockTenantInterceptor();
        registry.addInterceptor(mockTenantInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Edit: With Spring 5 / Spring Boot 2, `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated in favor of `implements WebMvcConfigurer` and uses Java 8's new default methods for interfaces.

See https://www.baeldung.com/web-mvc-configurer-adapter-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Isn't just injecting the interceptor an easier, cleaner way?

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private MyInterceptor interceptor;

@BeforeEach
public void before() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
      .standaloneSetup(controller)
      .addInterceptors(interceptor)
      .build();
}
```